# Lexical or preprocessor Issue: Exporting Cocos2D as a iOS framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ios-frameworks

I have an auto-generated Cocos2D iOS Application from Cocos Creator. Let's say [ProjectA](https://github.com/ramkrishnakuldeep/CocosHelloWorld)
(path to the iOS project /build/jsb-link/frameworks/runtime-src)

It has a reference to the (cocos2d_lib.xcodeproj) which is not in the same folder as the ProjectA.

I am able to export ProjectA as a framework(FrameworkA) with the required dependencies and libraries (also has cocos2d_iOS.a)

When I import the FrameworkA into another iOS [ProjectB](https://github.com/ramkrishnakuldeep/TestCocosFramework). I get the following error

[image]

The CCApplication.h is a file in the cocos2d_lib.xcodeproj